# UploadFileAsync not supported in silverlight 5 (Are you missing assembly reference)

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-applications, webclient, silverlight-5.0

I am using `Silverlight-5` ,`VS-2010 Express` and `SP-1` and i am C# beginner and trying to upload a file on Browse button click. My GUI is like this http://prntscr.com/34tevq but when i try to write this line in my code

`client.UploadFileAsync(filename, fileChunks[index]);` (where `WebClient client = new WebClient();`) then it gives red line under `UploadFileAsync` and the error is :

```
'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'UploadFileAsync' and no extension method 'UploadFileAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My c# code is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace shekhar_Final
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        List<byte[]> fileChunks;
        int chunkSize, index;
        string filename;
        double filesize, senddata;



        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            chunkSize = 4096;
            filesize = 0;
            index = 0;
            senddata = 0;
            filename=null ;
            fileChunks=null;


        }


        public void browse_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            if ((bool)ofd.ShowDialog())
            {
                filename = ofd.File.Name;
                FileStream fs = ofd.File.OpenRead();
                filesize = (double)fs.Length;
                textBox1.Text = filename;
                index = 0;
                senddata = 0;

                byte[] file = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(file, 0, file.Length);
                ConvertToChunks(file);
                prgUpload.Maximum = fileChunks.Count;
                prgUpload.Value = 0;
                uploadChunks(index);
            }
        }
        private void ConvertToChunks(byte[] imagefile)
        {
            double totalChunks = Math.Ceiling((double)imagefile.Length / (double)chunkSize);
            fileChunks = new List<byte[]>();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++)
            {
                byte[] chunks;
                int startIndex = i * chunkSize;
                if (startIndex + chunkSize > imagefile.Length)
                    chunks = new byte[imagefile.Length - startIndex];
                else
                    chunks = new byte[chunkSize];
                Array.Copy(imagefile,startIndex,chunks,0,chunks.Length);
                fileChunks.Add(chunks);
            }          
        }

        private void uploadChunks(int index)
        {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.UploadFileAsync(filename, fileChunks[index]);
           //this UploadFileAsync is not even in sky blue color in my VS code.
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //to be done
        }
    }
}
```

Am i missing assembly reference ? If yes ? then which ? Would be a great help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight's WebClient [doesn't have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_methods%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) a method called `UploadFileAsync`. The desktop runtimes do, however.

You should use [`OpenWriteAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144217%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on WebClient, then handle the [`OpenWriteCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openwritecompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event handler and write to the Stream.

Alternatively you can find an alternative solution to WebClient, such as working with the lower-level [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class or a 3rd party library.

Comment: thansk for the reply but what personally do you suggest me to use for uploading a file in c# and xml created GUI IN SILVERLIGHT 5 ?